How can I NAT traffic to a switch without a gateway via nftables?
I have an internal network, 10.32.0.0/16. I have two switches with management interfaces on a private subnet without a gateway (switch-a = 192.168.50.11 and switch-b = 192.168.50.12). I have a double-homed server jumpbox with IPs 10.0.0.5 and 192.168.50.5. I have added IPs 10.32.1.11 and 10.0.1.12 to the double-homed server's external NIC with 10.32.0.5. I would like to be able to talk to the switches via the two extra IPs on jumpbox.
My existing ruleset:
#!/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state invalid counter drop
        ct state {related, established} counter accept
        iifname "lo" counter accept
        ip saddr 127.0.0.0/8 ip daddr 127.0.0.0/8 counter accept
        ip saddr 192.168.50.0/24 counter accept
        ip saddr 10.32.0.0/16 counter accept
        counter log prefix "INPUT DROPPED: "
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        ip saddr 10.32.0.0/16 ip daddr 192.168.50.11 counter accept
        ip saddr 10.32.0.0/16 ip daddr 192.168.10.12 counter accept
        ip saddr 192.168.50.11 ip daddr 10.32.0.0/16 counter accept
        ip saddr 192.168.50.12 ip daddr 10.32.0.0/16 counter accept
        counter log prefix "FORWARD DROPPED: "
    }   
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }   
}
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.32.1.11 dnat to 192.168.50.11
        ip daddr 10.32.1.12 dnat to 192.168.50.12
    }   
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.50.11 snat to 10.32.1.11
        ip saddr 192.168.50.12 snat to 10.32.1.12
    }
}
table ip route {
    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority srcnat + 1; policy accept;
        oifname "ens1f0np0" ip saddr 192.168.50.11 ip saddr set 10.32.1.11 counter
        oifname "eno1" ip daddr 192.168.50.11 ip saddr set 192.168.50.5 counter
        oifname "ens1f0np0" ip saddr 192.168.50.12 ip saddr set 10.32.1.12 counter
        oifname "eno1" ip daddr 192.168.50.12 ip saddr set 192.168.50.5 counter
    }
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority dstnat + 1; policy accept;
        iifname "ens1f0np0" ip daddr 10.32.1.11 ip daddr set 192.168.50.11 counter
        iifname "ens1f0np0" ip daddr 10.32.1.11 ip saddr set 192.168.50.5 counter
        iifname "ens1f0np0" ip daddr 10.32.1.12 ip daddr set 192.168.50.12 counter
        iifname "ens1f0np0" ip daddr 10.32.1.12 ip saddr set 192.168.50.5 counter
    }
}

This all works up until jumpbox gets the return traffic. My understanding is that I need to use the conntrack functions to track the connection and restore the original source/destination. However, I'm not quite following all of the related documentation and examples I've come across so far. So how do I complete the circuit?
